# Postman API delete functionality issue

Tags: api, django-rest-framework, postman

I have the following in urls:

```
path('api/delete/<int:pk>/', views.Person.as_view())
```

and I'm testing with postman, which I'm new to.  inside the query params, I type

```
pk as the key and 4 as the value
```

with delete selected and ...:8000/api/delete/?pk=4/

I get a 404 HTTP error, suggesting Not found: /api/delete/

This is my delete functionality.

```
def delete(self, request, pk):
    print('inside delete')
    person = self.get_object(pk)
    print(person)
    person.delete()
    person.save()
    return Response(status = status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

It never enters the delete which would suggest it's an issue with my path.

Thanks

Trace:

```
Internal Server Error: /api/deletestory/2/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/John/Desktop/proj/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/John/Desktop/proj/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Users/John/Desktop/proj/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 124, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/John/Desktop/proj/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/John/Desktop/proj/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 68, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/John/Desktop/proj/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 495, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/Users/John/Desktop/proj/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 455, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/Users/John/Desktop/proj/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 492, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
TypeError: delete() got multiple values for argument 'pk'
[10/Mar/2019 07:30:54] "DELETE /api/delete/2/ HTTP/1.1" 500 14281
```

view:

```
class Person(APIView):

    def get_object(self, pk):
        try:
            print('inside get object')
            return Person.objects.get(pk = pk)
        except Person.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404

    def get(self, request, pk):
        print('inside get')
        person = self.get_object(pk)
        serializer = PersonSerializer(person)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def delete(self, pk):
        print('inside delete')
        person = self.get_object(pk)
        print(person)
        person.delete()
        return Response(status = status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

Comment: I've tried this too. http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/delete/4

Comment: Can you add your complete view?

Comment: hey @jpg, Yea no worries, I've added the view for you. Cheers

Comment: Your `delete()` method of the view isn't same in both examples? Is that a typo?

Comment: I can't believe, I've had this issue because of a typo! Thanks for your help! This sorted it out. I feel like a right idiot.

Answer (score 3):

You should make a `DELETE` request to: `127.0.0.1:8000/api/delete/4/` **(notice the trailing slash)**

[image: postman screenshot]

Comment: Hi there, Thanks for your response, I've tried this now I get a Type Error: delete() got multiple values for argument 'pk'  any ideas oh this ? Thanks for your assistance

Comment: Internal Server Error: /api/delete/2/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/John/Desktop/proj/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/John/Desktop/proj/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

Comment: sorry about the multiple messages its a long trace. Thanks again

Comment: @OrangeSubmarine121 You should have add the traceback to the question portion, so that it's become more readable

Comment: @jpg good point! I've done this now. Any ideas by any chance? Thanks for your help